# why MongoDB send error 500 when duplicated key

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

when recived the answer from MongoDB, know that my error is a duplicate key but why status=500 ?, it should be 4**.
I'm using nodejs (sails/express.js)

```
{   "error": {
    "error": "E_UNKNOWN",
    "status": 500,
    "summary": "Encountered an unexpected error",
    "raw": {
      "name": "MongoError",
      "code": 11000,
      "err": "E11000 duplicate key error index: eReporterDB.users.$name_1 dup key: { : \"codin\" }"
    }   } }
```

Comment: Dude, that's Mongo, not Postgres.

Comment: You're probably getting a 500 because MongoDB is raising an exception that isn't being caught by anything, that's a server error not a client error.

Comment: this happen in postgres too.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is [here](https://www.joyent.com/developers/node/design/errors) for nodejs

> Operational errors vs. programmer errors
>
> It's helpful to divide all errors into two broad categories:
>
> Operational errors represent run-time problems experienced by correctly-written programs. These are not bugs in the program. In
>   fact, these are usually problems with something else: the system
>   itself (e.g., out of memory or too many open files), the system's
>   configuration (e.g., no route to a remote host), the network (e.g.,
>   socket hang-up), or a remote service (e.g., a 500 error, failure to
>   connect, or the like). Examples include:
>
> ```
>     failed to connect to server
>     failed to resolve hostname
>     **invalid user input**
>     request timeout
>     server returned a 500 response
>     socket hang-up
>     system is out of memory
> ```
>
> Programmer errors are bugs in the program. These are things that can always be avoided by changing the code. They can never be handled
>   properly (since by definition the code in question is broken).
>           tried to read property of "undefined"
>           called an asynchronous function without a callback
>           passed a "string" where an object was expected
>           passed an object where an IP address string was expected